# Sequelize - Query to Sequelize methods

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize for a node project but I'm having some trouble converting a query in a Sequelize way.

Scenario: I have 2 tables (*User* and *Event*) with a n:m relation through *UserEvent* table. In *UserEvent* table there is *is_creator* attribute; what I need is an object with event name, event id and is_creator field.

Example:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "Event",
    is_creator: true
}]
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `Event`.`id`,`Event`.`name` as `Name`, `UserEvents`.`is_creator` AS `is_creator` FROM `Events` AS `Event` INNER JOIN (`UserEvents` INNER JOIN `Users` AS `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = `UserEvents`.`UserId`) ON `Event`.`id` = `UserEvents`.`EventId` AND `Users`.`id` = 1;
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to "translate" it to Sequelize.

Actual code:

```
var queryOptions: FindOptions = {
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.User,
                    where: {
                        id: user.id
                    }
                }
            ],
        };
```

Query executed:

```
SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`uuid`, `Event`.`image`, `Event`.`name`, `Event`.`start_at`, `Event`.`end_at`, `Event`.`location`, `Event`.`description`, `Event`.`createdAt`, `Event`.`updatedAt`, `Users`.`id` AS `Users.id`, `Users`.`uuid` AS `Users.uuid`, `Users`.`email` AS `Users.email`, `Users`.`password` AS `Users.password`, `Users`.`firstName` AS `Users.firstName`, `Users`.`lastName` AS `Users.lastName`, `Users`.`activationCode` AS `Users.activationCode`, `Users`.`resetCode` AS `Users.resetCode`, `Users`.`active` AS `Users.active`, `Users`.`dob` AS `Users.dob`, `Users`.`image` AS `Users.image`, `Users`.`createdAt` AS `Users.createdAt`, `Users`.`updatedAt` AS `Users.updatedAt`, `Users.UserEvent`.`uuid` AS `Users.UserEvent.uuid`, `Users.UserEvent`.`is_creator` AS `Users.UserEvent.is_creator`, `Users.UserEvent`.`createdAt` AS `Users.UserEvent.createdAt`, `Users.UserEvent`.`updatedAt` AS `Users.UserEvent.updatedAt`, `Users.UserEvent`.`UserId` AS `Users.UserEvent.UserId`, `Users.UserEvent`.`EventId` AS `Users.UserEvent.EventId` FROM `Events` AS `Event` INNER JOIN (`UserEvents` AS `Users.UserEvent` INNER JOIN `Users` AS `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = `Users.UserEvent`.`UserId`) ON `Event`.`id` = `Users.UserEvent`.`EventId` AND `Users`.`id` = 1;
```

Thanks in advance for your cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to limit the number of columns that your query is returning?

You can look at the `attributes` option. You can specify the table fields that you want.

For example, if you want the id, email and firstName of a user, you can specify it this way.

```
var queryOptions: FindOptions = {
        include: [
            {
                model: db.User,
                where: {
                    id: user.id
                },
                attributes: ['id', 'email', 'firstName']
            }
        ],
    };
```

You can similarly add the attributes option for the UserEvents table.

PS: I currently, do not have enough reputation to add comments on questions. Otherwise I would've done that.